# Prisma Studio Image in Docker can't be pulled

Tags: docker, prisma

I'm trying to run the prisma-studio container but  I'm getting an error that I don't know how to solve yet I followed the  [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/timothyjmiller/prisma-studio) steps.

**My docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  prisma-studio:
    container_name: prisma-studio
    image: timothyjmiller/prisma-studio:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - '5555:5555' 
    env_file: 
    - ./server/.env

    depends_on: 
      - db
     
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports: 
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file: 
    - ./server/.env
    volumes:
      - ./server/.dbdata:/var/lib/posgtgres

  api: 
    container_name: api
    build: 
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev      
    ports: 
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  client: 
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - api

volumes: 
  .dbdata:
```

**The error I'm getting**

```
Pulling prisma-studio (timothyjmiller/prisma-studio:latest)...
ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

What am I doing wrong with prisma-studio since it's the only image that's problematic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? If so, you need to make sure that it is configured correctly before pulling an image: If you are in a corporate network, you’ll most likely use a proxy server. If Docker tries to connect to DockerHub directly without using the corporate proxy, you may receive different error messages.